# How are declarations in a SML program separated?

Tags: sml, ml

In [SML's grammar](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml.html)

> Programs
>
> ```
> prog ::=   dec core declaration
>            functor fctbind functor declaration
>            signature sigbind signature declaration
>            empty
>            prog1 ⟨;⟩ prog2 sequence
>
> fctbind ::= id1 ( id2 : sig ) ⟨:⟨>⟩ sig⟩ = str ⟨and fctbind⟩    plain
> id ( spec ) ⟨:⟨>⟩ sig⟩ = str ⟨and fctbind⟩ opened
> sigbind    ::= id = sig ⟨and sigbind⟩ signature
> ```

Why

```
val a = 1
val b = 2;

a
b
```

has error between `a` and `b`, but not between the two val declarations?

```
$sml < main.sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
- val a = 1 : int
val b = 2 : int
= stdIn:4.1-5.2 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: int
  in expression:
    a b
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In

```ml
val a = 1
val b = 2
```

All you've done is bind two variables, corresponding to the rules
`dec ::= val ⟨var⟩(,) valbind`, `dec ::= dec1 ⟨;⟩ dec2`, and at top level, 
`prog ::= dec`.

Then in

```ml
a
b
```

You're actually attempting to *apply* `a` to `b` (`exp ::= exp1 exp2    (application)`). It might be simpler to see it as the equivalently written

```ml
a b
```

However, `a` doesn't have a function type, hence the error `operator is not a function`. It's unclear what you're actually attempting to do with `a` and `b`.